# How to convert a ASCII NULL (NUL) into single spacing in a text file using Unix command?

Tags: perl, shell, unix, awk, sed

When I BCP the data in sql server[image: Output file after BCP]

In the output file I am getting a NUL like character in the output file, and i want to replace this with the single blank space.

When I used the below `sed` command it removes the NUL character but between those 2 delimiter we don't have single space.

sed 's/\x0/ /g' output file name

Example: After sed command i am getting output file like below

```
PHMO||P00000005233
PHMO||P00000005752
```

But i need a single spacing in between those delimiter as

```
PHMO| |P00000005233
PHMO| |P00000005752
```

Comment: does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36305467/5832518) resolves your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach to this would be using `tr`.  However, solutions with `tr` and `sed` are not portable.  (The question is tagged "unix", so only portable solutions are interesting).

Here is a simple demo script

```
#!/bin/sh
date
tr '\000' ' ' <$0.in
date
sed -e 's/\x00/ /g' <$0.in
```

which I named `foo`, and its input (with the ASCII NUL shown here as `^@`):

```
this is a null: "^@"
```

Running with GNU `tr` and `sed`:

```
Fri Apr  1 04:41:15 EDT 2016
this is a null: " "
Fri Apr  1 04:41:15 EDT 2016
this is a null: " "
```

With OSX:

```
Fri Apr  1 04:41:53 EDT 2016
this is a null: " "
Fri Apr  1 04:41:53 EDT 2016
this is a null: "^@"
```

With Solaris 10 (and 11, though there may be a recent change):

```
Fri Apr  1 04:38:08 EDT 2016
this is a null: ""
Fri Apr  1 04:38:08 EDT 2016
this is a null: ""
```

Bear in mind that `sed` is line-oriented, and that ASCII NUL is considered a binary (*non*-line) character.  If you want a portable solution, then other tools such as Perl (which do not have that limitation) are useful.  For that case one could add this to the script:

```
perl -np -e 's/\0/ /g' <$0.in
```

The intermediate tool `awk` is no better in this instance.  Going to Solaris again, with these lines:

```
for awk in awk nawk mawk gawk
do
echo "** $awk:"
$awk '{ gsub("\0"," "); print; }' <$0.in
done
```

I see this output:

```
** awk:
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1
** nawk:
nawk: empty regular expression
 source line number 1
 context is
        { gsub("\0"," >>>  ") <<<
** mawk:
this is a null: " "
** gawk:
this is a null: " "
```

Further reading:

- [sed - stream editor](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) (POSIX)
- [tr - translate characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) (POSIX), which notes

> Unlike some historical implementations, this definition of the tr utility correctly processes NUL characters in its input stream. NUL characters can be stripped by using:
>
> `tr -d '\000'`

- [perlrun - how to execute the Perl interpreter](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy job for sed. Let's start creating a test file as you didn't provide one:

```
$ echo -e "one,\x00,two,\x00,three" > a
$ echo -e "four,\x00,five,\x00,six" >> a
```

As you can see it contains ASCII 0:

```
$ od -c a
0000000   o   n   e   ,  \0   ,   t   w   o   ,  \0   ,   t   h   r   e
0000020   e  \n   f   o   u   r   ,  \0   ,   f   i   v   e   ,  \0   ,
0000040   s   i   x  \n
0000044
```

Now let's run sed:

```
$ sed 's/\x00/ /g' a > b
```

And check the output:

```
$ cat b
one, ,two, ,three
four, ,five, ,six
$ od -c b
0000000   o   n   e   ,       ,   t   w   o   ,       ,   t   h   r   e
0000020   e  \n   f   o   u   r   ,       ,   f   i   v   e   ,       ,
0000040   s   i   x  \n
0000044
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done quite easily with `perl`

```
cat -v inputfile.txt
abc^@def^@ghij^@klmnop^@qrstuv^@wxyz

perl -np -e 's/\0/ /g' <inputfile.txt >outputfile.txt

cat -v outputfile.txt
abc def ghij klmnop qrstuv wxyz
```