# Match file with nulls portably

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file with data like:

```
blub\0test\0further\0
```

and would now like to test whether the exact content is in that file from shell.
What is a portable way (across *nixs) of testing that?

Ignoring any esoteric gnu, bash, etc. extensions please.

Comment: And it has to be a shell script?

Comment: Sadly yes shell script with basic core utils.

Comment: Maybe perl can do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304271/how-to-convert-a-ascii-null-nul-into-single-spacing-in-a-text-file-using-unix

Comment: `cmp localfile <(ssh user@server cat path/to/file)`

Comment: Several tools can produce an unambiguous ASCII dump of a binary file. See `hexdump` and `od`. You can also compute a checksum; for example, the `sha1sum` of that particular sequence is `615d71dc7bdad793e256c951406e2269f52096af`. Or, as @janos suggests, you can compare it to a known good file (if both are locally available).

Comment: ...excluding "esoteric" extensions only -- so mundane bash extensions are allowed?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what "basic core utils" means. I presume you're not referring to the [GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) package. Exactly what restrictions are you operating under? [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/xcu.html) perhaps?

Comment: @KeithThompson _Currently_ I would say, various Linux variants, macOS, Cygwin, mingw.

Comment: You mean utilities common to all those systems, yes? That still may not be precise enough. there are minimal Linux-based systems that may lack some of the utilities you'd normally expect to be present. Please **update the question** to give us a better idea of just what the restrictions are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare a file content (or actually any large content) you may use md5.

Fortunately, bash has md5sum! so you can get a corresponding "value" for each content.

```
md5sum yourfile
```

If you store the content you are looking for in another file (let's say cmpval) you can use:

```
md5sum yourfile > tmp
cmp tmp cmpval
rm tmp
```

Comment: That is a *Useless Use of cat*. Use `md5sum < yourfile` or `md5sum yourfile`. You might also want to strip the extra information that `md5sum` prints (which might vary from one implementation to another). You might also consider using `sha1sum` instead (though *unintentional* `md5sum` collisions are still unlikely).

Comment: not true, if you do what you said you wouldn't be able to compare it with the content he wants...

Comment: What? Is `*yourfile*` supposed to be a wildcard? `cat filename | md5sum` does exactly the same thing as `md5sum < filename`. Incidentally, `md5sum` isn't part of bash; it's a separate command (which is *probably* available on almost all systems).

Comment: the '*' was a mistake but it meant for the file name and path... but I got what you meant and you are right, it is useless :P fixed it